# Why was Styxx at Acheron's wedding when Acheron hates Styxx?

Tags: dark-hunter

In the Dark Hunter series we find in "Acheron", in the epilogue pg. 718, when discussing the groomsmen, it says that

> Kim was with Vane, Geary was with her husband Airk, Katra with her husband Sin, Danger with Alexion-both of whom were in temporary human bodies.  Simi was with Zarek, Justina with Kyrian, Katherina with ***Styxx*** and Aimee was there with Dev.

Assuming that the dates actually work out, why would Styxx be at the wedding when Acheron hates Styxx at that time?  They are still enemies after Styxx sent Sebastos a gift on May 14th 2012.  They only make up after Acheron spoke to Urian on June 25th 2012.  This is years after the wedding takes place.  So why is Styxx there?

Answer (score 1):

Well it was an epilogue there could possibly have been a time skip.

IIRC though for Styxx to be alive that thing where they lived each others lives had to have already happened which would at least start the reconciliation process possibly enough for Styxx to attend the wedding

EDIT:  Also I am not certain of all the relationships involved but its possible the woman Styxx was with was a really good friend or relative and put her foot down "if you want me at the wedding then he has to be there to"